# How can the standard deviation be interpreted when the range is partially impossible?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

After meassuring the answer time of a software system I calculated the standard deviation from the samples. The average time is about 200ms, the standard deviation $$\sigma = 300ms$$ According to the image below this should mean that 68.2% of all response times should be between -100ms and 500ms.

[image]
<sup>Image:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation</sup>

A negative response time makes obviously no sense. How should the part of the normal distribution be interpreted that is enclosed in the red box?

Sample data with similiar avg ~202 stddev ~337:

```
100
100
200
150
70
90
110
80
150
70
190
110
130
100
100
1500
```

Comment: Why you have assumed normal distribution?

Comment: This means that hypothesis about normal distribution of answer time is a poor one. If your software has "distribution" parameter, you may try "Poisson".

Comment: Maybe try lognormal

Comment: Related: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925073)

Comment: Note that even with $\sigma=0.1\,\text{ms}$ "the raneg is partially impossible", it's just "only" a tail at $2000\sigma$

Comment: @luka5z That was because the related wikipedia article suggests the relationship. I had this σ=300ms and wanted know what it means.

Comment: @stacker could you make screenshot of the particular fragment and post it?

Comment: @luka5z Actually I've 50.000 samples but it would be the similiar to the sample set I added to the question.

Comment: @stacker Rather than posting a tiny sample with one HUGE (unrepresentative) outlier from a big data set, how about you post a histogram of the whole data set?

Comment: @stacker are you familiar with R-project? See script in my edited answer.

Comment: Haven't you considered to take out the 1500 outlier?

Comment: @luka5z Thank you, I'm going to will download R, looks promising.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans No, very few (<< 1%) are really extreme outlier

Comment: @stacker You will get the best result if you use big sample (~1000). Anyway, statistics is all about testing. You can test your sample against any nonnegative distribution. $R$ will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Any time I generate statistics that appear impossible or absurd, my first assumption is always that I've made a poor choice of model for my data.

Comment: Try to remember that normally distributions are not normal . . .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have assumed a normal distribution for a data which cannot be negative. It doesn't make sense at all. You can use lognormal distribution instead. It is used in Black-Scholes model for pricing options. (Stock prices cannot be negative)

Obviously, I can't tell you if your sample fits such a distribution if I don't have access to the full dataset.

r-script:

```
require(MASS)
hist(x, freq=F)
fit<-fitdistr(x,"log-normal")$estimate
lines(dlnorm(0:max(x),fit[1],fit[2]), lwd=3)
```

(x is a sample vector)

[image]

Obviously, your sample is way too small here.

Comment: To follow up on the title question, how can the standard deviation be interpreted if the distribution isn't normal? For example, is there any meaning to the standard deviation calculated on samples from a lognormal distribution?

Comment: @R.M. Standard deviation is one measure of dispersion. It has the same interpretation regardless of the distribution. Standard deviation informs you how much data drawn from a particular distribution will be, on average, "spread out" from its mean. Just look at the definition: $SD(X)=\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}X)^2}$. Note $Y=(X-\mathbb{E}X)^2$ is another random variable which describes squared distance of $X$ from its mean. If you calculate $\mathbb{E}Y$ you will know how much on average this distance is. We take square root to normalize (go back to original scale - not squared).

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, the normal distribution doesn't make much sense here.  We sometimes use a normal distribution, despite the possibility of  negative values that don't make sense, when the probability of such values under the normal distribution is very small.  But here the standard deviation is greater than the mean, so that probability is not small at all
(about $1/4$).

A glance at your data suggests that a heavy-tailed distribution might
be appropriate: much of the standard deviation comes from that one very large value of $1500$.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the square root of the weighted sum of the squares of the differences from the sample mean for any set of data.  All this calculation does is tell you how spread out the data are.

But, as you've suspected, saying that this dataset is normally distributed is likely nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

There's another issue that the other answers are not addressing. In applications like this one you're often **not interested** in the standard deviation, since it is a non-robust statistic with a breakdown point of 0%, which means that for a large sample size changing a negligible fraction of the data can result in an arbitrary change in the statistic's value. Instead, consider using quantiles, common ones being the inter-quantile range, which are more robust statistics. Specifically, the $25$-th and $75$-th quantiles both have 25% breakdown point, because you need to change at least 25% of the data to arbitrarily affect them.

This is particular important in your consideration, because of a number of factors:

1. Communication delays are often caused by one-time events that result in a down-time rather than a normal delay, and of course such down-times are very long in comparison. For example think of power outages, server crash, even sabotage...
2. Even if there are no down-times in your data, other factors could have a significant impact on your measurements that are completely irrelevant to your application. For example, other processes running in the background might slow down your application, or memory caching might be improving the speed for some but not all runs. There might even be occasional hardware activity that affects the speed of your application only now and then.
3. Usually people judge a system's responsiveness based on the average case, not the average of all cases. Most will accept that an operation might in a minority of the cases completely fail and never even return a response. An excellent example is the HTTP request. A small but nonzero proportion of packets get totally dropped from the internet and the request would have a theoretically infinite response time. Obviously people don't care and just press "Refresh" after a while.

Comment: Very well-suited.

Comment: @A.S.: Thanks! I always find it surprising that people don't seem to teach such statistics, even though it is in fact used in practice. Another good thing is that the quantiles always exist and can be estimated even if the mean doesn't, same for the inter-quantile range. There are even CLT-like theorems for the quantiles. Yet none of my statistics teachers ever even mentioned quantiles in statistical analysis!

Comment: Few academicians practice and for theoreticians variance is very convenient to operate on analytically - so it gets the most attention in non-applied courses. What I found most useful about your post wasn't so much a suggestion to use quantiles (there are other robust statistics) but all the tailored info relevant to performance of the *actual physical/customer* system. This is what should guide a choice of statistic/metric since doing any data analysis beyond histogramming before maximally fleshing out/thinking through peculiarities of the system at hand is futile and possibly misleading...//

Comment: //...  Just look above - somebody is already trying to fit a log-normal to a small sample from much bigger data set or suggest a heavy-tail distribution even though it's possibly a mixture based on whether a "one-time event" happened or not (which I wouldn't think of right away without reading your post).

Comment: @A.S.: Yea I saw the other post, which is why I posted my answer since I've dealt with such one-time events many times before in timing tests. As for my suggestion to use quantiles, what other robust statistics do you have in mind that can do the job well in this case? I suggested using quantiles because it doesn't presume anything at all about the distribution, but I don't know much about other robust statistics, so I'd be glad if you could tell me a bit more!

Comment: I'm far from an expert on robust statistics, but you could first trim your distribution and *then* compute the mean (and STD/MAD though it's not standard) as measures of centering/spread. This would be more appropriate if, for example, requests came in "buckets" in which case while you can drop/time-out some percentage of request, you still care about mean time to fulfill the "bucket" which is presented by the trimmed mean. Quantiles seem more appropriate for "rare events". The given data set would be well described by trimmed mean and MAD (or $5-95\%$-range).

Comment: @A.S.: Ah yes, I read about trimming, but I would question whether the mean of the trimmed data is that useful a statistic since the presence of outliers do mean that the trimmed mean does not reflect the average time after all. If however we do want the mean of the middle 90% range of response times, then of course we estimate precisely that. I guess it boils down to what you said earlier, which is that we need to decide what exactly we want to quantify before looking for a way to estimate it.

Comment: In your HTTP example (which made me think of the trimmed mean), if we trim at the point where people say "Refresh", we'll get exactly the expected time of the request *serviced*. Or we could collapse the right tail into the "refresh" point to get mean time per request - fulfilled or not. The point is not completely forgo the mean - which estimates *long term average* - in favor of median/quantile range - which, in some sense, tells you the range *for a single request* you are likely to get after at most a few repeated requests.

Comment: @A.S.: Exactly; in the HTTP example we'd first have to determine that the question we want to answer is not actually about the system response time but the time people take to get their webpage, refresh and all, and excluding people who give up and go somewhere else. Then it makes perfect sense to trim the data beyond that point in some way or another like you suggested.

Comment: @A.S.: That said, I believe as stated in my answer that people judge responsiveness more based on median waiting time than mean waiting time. Similar quantile-based analysis easily explains the intuition that there is a limit to how much one should pay to play the St Petersburg lottery, likewise triple-or-nothing, where the limit is dependent on the player's risk preference. But I don't have the empirical data for my claim that people's risk analysis is influence by perceived quantiles.

Comment: I agree with you as for HTTP example since people load pages once in a while and are not that sensitive to small variation of time (plus perception of time is non-linear) and basically people care that "approx every other request will land in $[Q_1,Q_3]$ - if this one doesn't work fast, the next one will". But if I was attempting to load 100 pages sequentially - many times a day - I'd judge performance by total time of service which would be best reflected by the trimmed mean. As for your claim, it's very plausible since estimating probabilities is way easier than estimating expected values.

Comment: How would quantile-based analysis explain people buying more tickets of the same lottery when jackpot grows - most quantiles stay the same, but people still respond to widening range and increased expected value - though I think it's mostly the former.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33138/discussion-between-user21820-and-a-s).

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you fallback to the most infamous distribution -- the normal distribution -- to interpret your results. This is not the only one, and in your case is a poor choice: indeed, the normal distribution is symmetric around its mean, and has support $\mathbb{R}$: in your case, an asymmetric distribution putting probability mass only on the positive reals would make more sense, if you really want to compare against a "known" model of probability distributions.

(Note that the notion of variance does not depend on the normal distribution, nor on any particular distribution.)